# Concepto de Clases y Objetos en Javascript

Tags: javascript, poo, objeto, clase, javascript-objeto

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Javascript usando el libro "El gran libro de html5, css y javascript" (2017).

Ahora mismo estoy en la parte de "Objetos" en el libro (POO), pero estoy teniendo muchas dificultades a la hora de entender el concepto de Objetos que se plantea en el libro. He estudiado hace mucho tiempo otros lenguajes como C# y C++ y en ese entonces he comprendido el concepto de Clases y Objetos (el objeto es una instancia de la clase). Sin embargo, en este libro solo se está planteando el concepto de "Objetos" y como "crearlos" sin hacer referencia a una CLASE y a una INSTANCIA DE CLASE. En su lugar, me plantean crear un objeto y su constructor de esta forma:

```
var Constructor = function(valor){
    var nombre = valor;    // closure    
    var MiObjeto = {
        propiedad1: "valor1",
        propiedad2: "valor2",
        metodo: function(){
            alert("hola");
        }
    }
    return MiObjeto;
}
var instancia = Constructor("juan");
instancia.metodo();
```

En el libro no se refiere a "MiObjeto" como una clase, sino que lo nombra como un objeto aunque NO se lo haya instanciado. Como logré entender la idea en general un poco, pero aún me quedaron muchas dudas, decidí buscar videos en internet que también explicasen como funcionan las clases y objetos en Javascript. Sin embargo, ahora en estos videos me encuentro con que para usar objetos usan la palabra clave "Class", y SI hablan del concepto de clases y objetos tal y como lo recordaba de otros lenguajes como c# y c++:

```
class MiClase{
    constructori(valor){
       this.propiedad = valor;
    }
}
let perro = new MiClase("valor");
```

En general, estoy viendo que hay muchas formas diferentes de trabajar con Clases y Objetos en Javascript. En base a todo esto, mis preguntas serían las siguientes:

> 1- ¿El método que se está usando en el libro para usar Objetos es un
> método obsoleto?
>
> 2- ¿Debo seguir aprendiendo a trabajar con "Objetos" tal y como me lo
> está planteando el libro o debo buscar otras fuentes?
>
> 3- ¿Cual es el método que mas se está usando actualmente para trabajar
> con Objetos en javascript?.

Desde ya muchas gracias por leer, mis dudas nacen del hecho de que no quiero aprender a utilizar un método para el uso de Clases y objetos que ya no se está usando en la vida real.

Answer (score 2):

1. La forma en la que se crean los objetos en el libro es correcta, es una de las formas de instanciar objectos, tienes new Object(), Object.create() y la tercera que es usando las llaves con propiedades dentro llamada notación literal, puedes ver más aquí:

   [Object initializer MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

   [Trabajando con objetos MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)
2. Si, debes seguir como te dice en el libro ya que es la manera más común de trabajar con objetos en javaScript, aunque te recomiendo buscar javascript con ES6 para entender mejor algunas cosas, no sé qué usará la explicación de tu libro
3. Al menos por mi parte utilizo bien seguido la de notación literal

```
const coche = {
  marca: 'bmw',
  modelo: 'm3'
}

console.log(typeof coche) //retorna 'object'
```

Te dejo un articulo donde mencionan cuatro formas de crear objetos en javaScript además mencionan que con ES6 se introduce la keyword class para crear clases, con eso será más parecido a lo que est

[Four Ways to Create Objects in JavaScript](https://dzone.com/articles/easy-javascript-part-13-four-ways-to-create-object#:%7E:text=There%20are%20four%20ways%20to,as%20using%20a%20function%20constructor)

No soy un crack, estoy aprendiendo aún así que cualquier comentario será bien recibido, muchas gracias !

Answer (score 0):

como complemento a lo que te contesto la persona de arriba, JavaScript es un lenguaje de programacion que acepta el paradigma orientado a objetos pero no se limita por el en absoluto, pues tambien tiene caracteristicas de la programacion funcional. Por otro lado si bien pueden crearse objetos instanciando clases, JS es un lenguaje basado en prototipos y no en clases aunque estas pueden crearse por lo tanto el paradigma de la POO en Javascript se aplica de forma diferente a por ejemplo, Java, donde es estrictamente con clases. Podes leer la documentacion oficial para informarte mas sobre JS y la programacion basada en prototipos:

[mas sobre la programacion basada en prototipos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript es un lenguaje de prototipo de objetos, no de clases.

Se puede usar el azúcar sintáctico ES6 siempre y cuando sean pocos elementos, ya que cuando son grandes volúmenes de objetos instancias entonces se carga en memoria, porque la clase hace el trabajo de anexarlo al prototipo pero usa más memoria. Es por esta razón que hay productos hechos en *frameworks* que se ponen lentos y la gente no entiende por qué, y ahí está la razón.

Es bueno que se aprenda la forma moderna `class` y la antigua `Object.create`:

```
Object.prototype ,function App();
```

NOTA: Otro asunto con la creación de `class App {}`: no puedes darle `Object.defineproperties`, o sea cualidades de estilo, no puedes usar enumerable, configurable, writable, porque no lo soporta.

**Por ejemplo:**

```
function App(name,apel) {
    this.name = name;
    this.apel = apel;
}
App.prototype = {
    constructor : Object,   
    llamada : function(){
        return `ok ${this.name} ${this.apel}`
},
    verificar : function(ar){
        if(ar instanceof App){
        return `Valor recibido ${ar.llamada()}`
        }
}
}


function App2(name,apel) {
App.call(this,name,apel);
}
/*
App2.prototype = new App();
App2.prototype.constructor = App2;
*/
App2.prototype = Object.create(App.prototype,{
    constructor : {
        value : App2,
        writable : true,
        configurable: true,
        enumerable : true,
}
})

class App3 extends App {
    constructor(name,apel){
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.apel = apel;
    }
}

const cliente1 = new App("Joan ", "Peralta");
const cliente2 = new App2("Joana ", "Perez");
const cliente3 = new App3("Yiselle ", "Peralta"); 
const cliente4 = new App3("Pamela" , "Perez");

console.log(cliente1.verificar(cliente2));
console.log(cliente1.verificar(cliente3));
```